# Is there any way to observe specific actions on database using Room?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room

[This](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries#observable) docs provide a way to observe data stored in database. But this is too generic. This emits a new value whenever any changes occur to that table. Using this to update `recyclerView` means, on every update I have to replace old dataset by new one and call `notifyDatasetChanged` on the adapter. But instead is there any to specifically get updates like `onRowInserted`, `onRowUpdated` and `onRowDeleted` which returns only the data in the row being modified, as this helps me in making specific `notifyItemInserted`, `notifyItemChanged` and `notifyItemRemoved` calls to the adapter.

Comment: Why not use the `RecyclerView` edition of `ListAdapter`, which will perform those calculations for you?

Comment: @CommonsWare What's that? link please..

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter

Comment: Thanks :)  Is this the best suitable solution?

Comment: For `RecyclerView`, yes. Jetpack Compose basically uses the same approach for everything. What you want is not offered by SQLite. So, at most, Room could do the same thing that `ListAdapter` does, and doing that for *everything* would be a waste of resources. So, Room delegates that downstream to `ListAdapter`, Jetpack Compose, or other things.

Comment: @CommonsWare I can save a list of listeners in DAO, then wrap Room's Insert, Delete and Update functions in another function, which calls appropriate listener methods when those methods are called and a successful action occurs. Now, is it good enough, and is it worth doing?

Comment: "Now, is it good enough, and is it worth doing?" -- I have no way of answering that, sorry